# WCF: XmlSerialization attribute ignored for the root element

Tags: xml, wcf, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm working on a REStful WCF service that returns XML generated by the XML Serializer (as opposed to the `DataContract` serializer).

Whilst most objects are formatted correctly, the root element of what is returned seems to be ignoring my XML serialization attributes.

For example, the resource `/accounts/` returns an XML serialized representation of my AccountList class (itself a subclass of my own `ObjectList<T>` class which has some properties on it that should be serialized). However I'm not getting the results I want.

Here is my code:

```cs
[XmlRoot("accounts")]
public class AccountList : ObjectList<Account> {
}

public class ObjectList<T> : List<T> {
    [XmlAttribute("foo")]
    public Int32 FooProperty { get; set; }
}

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate="/accounts")]
public AccountList GetAccounts() {
    return new AccountList() {
        new Account("bilbo baggins"),
        new Account("steve ballmer")
    };
}
```

And this is what is returned by the web service:

```
<arrayOfAccount>
    <Account>
        <name>biblo baggins</name>
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <name>steve ballmer</name>
    </Account>
</arrayOfAccount>
```

So the main problem is that my desired serialization on the AccountList class is being ignored, and I'd also like to know how to get it so "Account" is in lowercase like the "name" property is (I used [XmlElement("name")] on those properties and it works fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this will work but try adding the following attributes to the method:

```
[return:XmlArray("accounts")]
[return:XmlArrayItem("account")]
```

Update:

The above does not work due to the [return:*] attributes not getting picked up. two options that do work:

you can make AccountList contain a list, and use [XmlElement("account")] there, like so:

```
[XmlRoot("accounts")]
public class AccountList : ObjectList<Account> {
    [XmlElement("account")]
    public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectList<T> {//: List<T> {
    [XmlAttribute("foo")]
    public Int32 FooProperty { get; set; }
}
```

alternatively, if you don't mind varying the response xml, you can add a wrapper class and use [XmlArray] and [XmlarrayItem] as described before:

```
[XmlRoot("response")]
public class GetAccountResponse {
  [XmlArray("accounts"), XmlArrayItem("account")]
  public AccountList Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, seems the [return:*] attributes aren't getting picked up, too bad.